# No apps showing in Ubuntu Software

Tags: gnome, software-center

I just installed a free image of Ubuntu 22.04. All seems well so far apart from the software store. No apps are showing at all in the categories or search.

I followed a lot of steps in this article with reinstalling `gnome-software refresh` & `sudo apt reinstall gnome-software` but no change thus far.

I know I can download the apps from terminal but would still like to try and get Ubuntu Software working.

Here are some errors I saw in the terminal and in Ubuntu Software. Any insight would be appreciated.

[image: terminal]

[image: app]

Kind regards

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick replies. All is well now. Just bad timing on my end 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Snapcraft.io was down a little while ago, see [Snapcraft System Status](https://status.snapcraft.io/). You can see that this is a server issue rather than an issue with your computer by looking at the error message "unexpected HTTP status code 503". HTTP status code 503 means "service unavailable," meaning that the Ubuntu Software app cannot communicate with the servers where the software is because the servers are having an issue.

The services should be operational now, and Ubuntu Software should now be working.